# vimL sleep within a function

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to define a function that will make it easier to see where the cursor is location by putting cross-hairs around it for 100ms.

Here's my attempt:

```
function! Flash()
    set cursorline cursorcolumn
    sleep 100m
    set nocursorline nocursorcolumn
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>fl :call Flash()
```

It seems though that the above function is calling the sleep at the beginning rather than in between the two "set" calls.

Is there something fundamental about "sleep" that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Came here trying to do something similar. You don't even need a function, you could map the commands directly on the map line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that Vim doesn't redraw the screen until after the function is completed. I'm not sure what Vim's logic on when to redraw is *exactly*, but in this sort of case you often have to call `redraw` manually:

```
function! Flash()
    set cursorline cursorcolumn
    redraw
    sleep 100m
    set nocursorline nocursorcolumn
endfunction
```

You probably also want to add `<CR>` to the key mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>fl :call Flash()<CR>
```