# Cursorline/Columnline slowdown

Tags: syntax-highlighting, scrolling, cursorline, redraw

I have recently recompiled vim, and ever since, when I have a big file, the scrolling gets slow. `cursorline` seems to be the problem; it doesn't matter if I use any of my plugins, if I have `cursorline` on, then the redrawing (and thus, the scrolling) gets slower, and the syntax highlight, while on its own inoffensive, when combined with `cursorline` makes the redrawing process *very* slow. Pretty much all of the solutions I have seen to this problem include either removing the syntax highlight or the `cursorline`; however, I was wondering if it would be possible to solve this some way. I have also already tried using `set lazyredraw`, `set ttyfast`, `set foldmethod=manual` and `set synmaxcol=128`, with no better results. Does anybody have more ideas?

Comment: I think you will not find anything more than what you already read: cursorline highlighting is one of the few things in vim which doesn't work that well. To workaround this problem I made a [small plugin](https://github.com/statox/gutterline.vim) which puts a sign in the gutter where the current line is. It is still a work in progress but it seems to be working ok, you can have a look if you don't find a better solution.

Comment: You can also have a look at [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3481/1841) posted by Carpetsmoker, that's a good way to quickly locate your cursor.

Comment: @statox Thank you for your answers, perhaps you can post them as an actual answer (instead of comments)? Great plugin, though I altered some things: I set `g:GutterLineSign` to `▸` instead of `>`, and added `set updatetime=500` to my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Known [problem](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2584)

Comment: What's "Columnline"? Is it a plugin? A typo? It's not mentioned anywhere in the question body. (Do you mean cursorcolumn?)

Answer (score 2):

As @Christian Brabandt pointed out in the comment this is [a known issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2584) and there might not be a lot of solutions, for now, to make `cursorline` work properly.

However, you can use different workarounds:

- In [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/viml-sleep-within-a-function/3481#3481) @Carpetsmoker suggest a mapping which will set `cursorline` and `cursorcolumn` for a fraction of a second. This is pretty useful to easily locate your cursor.
- I also created [gutterline.vim](https://github.com/statox/gutterline.vim) which is a plugin which simply adds a sign in the gutter where your cursor is it was meant to be as simple as possible and the result is something like this:

[image: gutterline screenshot]